# My Javascript only works on one element in a python embedded for loop in Django2

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, audio

I'm iterating these html template cards using Python for loop and I have a javascript to go with it. The problem is that the javascript is only working on the first element (the script is basically getting the seeked position of the audio) and not the rest. I thought it was because I set an id of the template card instead of a class name, but I am still getting the same results. The Javascript is in the for loop. Maybe it shouldn't? Anyways here is my code:

```
{% for song in songs %}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <img class="card-img-top" id="img_size"
                         src="{{ song.song_image.url }}"
                         alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="my-header">
                        <h3 id="song_title">{{ song.song_title }}</h3>
                        <span id="pub_date">{{ song.publishing_date }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">{{ song.song_description }}</p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <audio class="myAudio" controls>
                                    <source src="{{ song.song_file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                                    <source src="{{ song.song_file.url }}" type="audio/wav">
                                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                                </audio>
                                <script>
                                    var vid = document.getElementsByClassName("myAudio");

                                    function getCurTime() {
                                        alert(vid.currentTime);
                                    }

                                    function setCurTime() {
                                        vid.currentTime=5;
                                    }
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: why putting your script inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

1. No the JavaScript shouldn't be in the loop.
2. In your loop you're not creating unique identifiers for your audio elements. An easy way to do so could be done by using `{{ forloop.counter }}` in the class (or any other) attribute of your audio tag, and then call it in your JavaScript.

Please let me know if you need more help.